# Tensorflow mobilenet use models offline

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, mobilenet

Im using mobilenet from tensorflow and are trying to load the models offline.

The model loads here:

```
tf.loadModel(this.path)]
```

My first approach was to simply download the model.json and point to that file instead of the full url in my code as follows:

```
   // this.path = 'https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/model.json';
   this.path = "./model.json";
```

But then I am getting the following error:
[image]

```
GET https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/group37-shard1of1 net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
weights_loader.js:47
```

How do I download and point correctly to the weights for use it offline?

---

**UPDATE**
I now just downloaded every shard manually by using the link in the errormessage.

> https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/group1-shard1of1
> https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/group1-shard1of1
> https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/group1-shard1of1
> and so on up to
> https://storage.googleapis.com/tfjs-models/tfjs/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224/group55-shard1of1

Now the groups loads correctly:
[image]

but I am getting a new errormessage:

> Error: Based on the provided shape, [1,1,1024,1000], and dtype
> float32, the tensor should have 1024000 values but has 410072

Answer (score 0):

when you download model.json you can see group1-shard1of2 and group1-shard2of2 text in that json

change these text to group1-shard1of2.txt and group1-shard2of2.txt

and put these files in your server location

and that will works well

Answer (score -1):

If you have tensorflow installed the MobileNet and MobileNet version 2 models are available as shown below. Documentation is [here.][1]. For original version you can get the weights for the model trained on the imagenet data set for image size 224 X 224 with the code below. There are four sets of pre-trained weights available for image sizes 224, 192,160,128 so select the one you want. Below I selected the weights for the 224 X 224 image size. The variable weights will contain the pre-trained weights.

```
image_size=224
mobile = tf.keras.applications.mobilenet.MobileNet( include_top=True,
                                                           input_shape=(image_size,image_size,3), weights='imagenet',alpha=1, depth_multiplier=1, dropout=.1)
model = Model(inputs=mobile.input, outputs=mobile.output)  
model.compile(Adamax(lr=.001), loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
weights=model.get_weights()


  [1]: https://keras.io/api/applications/mobilenet/
```

Comment: sorry, I dont really see how this helps me of running the tensorflows.js models offline?

Comment: I guess I do not understand what the problem is. What to you mean by " offline"

Comment: Well simply without being connected to internet :) As you can see it now tries to fetch the weights from googleapis. I want to save them and pull them locally so I can use them also when I dont have any internet connection available.

Comment: see modified answer . There are four possible sets of weights .

Comment: Thanks for this! Actually I now just downloaded every shard manually by using the link in the errormessage. See update above